# Typescript async/await structuring issue

Tags: typescript, async-await, es6-promise

I've been working on an interesting problem in my Typescript project (targeting es6). Basically, I want to be able to quickly define many different series of user input 'pages', in some undetermined order, and where the result of the previous page may or may not have some bearing on the construction of the next 'page'.

I'm therefore considering each page as a Promise constructed by a function (here `getPromise1()` etc) which resolves to a result once user input is completed. I then use async/await to create the pages in order.

```
async process() {
    let result1 = await this.getPromise1();

    let result2 = await this.getPromise2(result1.someData);

    //etc...

    this.commit();
}
```

This works well, however I've hit a snag. The page sequence can be cancelled at any stage via user input and thus the construction will need to abort at that point. The problem is, checking for cancellation at every single stage becomes tiresome and inelegant, and it feels very strongly to me like the wrong way to go.

```
async process() {
    let result1 = await this.getPromise1();
    if (result1.cancelled) {
        this.revert();
        return;
    }


    let result2 = await this.getPromise2(result1.someData);
    if (result2.cancelled) {
        this.revert();
        return;
    }

    //etc...

    this.commit();
}
```

Where have I gone wrong here? Am I using a completely incorrect pattern for this sort of setup? Is there a more elegant way to approach this method? Or is there really no better way to go about something like this?

Comment: FYI, `async/await` is not part of ES7.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution could be to have your 'pages' *reject* their promise (i.e. `throw` an error) so you can `catch` the error in your `process` function.

```
class App {

    async process() {
        try {
            let result1 = await this.getPromise1();

            let result2 = await this.getPromise2(result1.someData);

            //etc...

            this.commit();
        } catch (e) {
            this.revert();
        }
    }

    async getPromise1() {
        return {someData: 'foo'};
    }

    async getPromise2({someData}) {
        throw new Error('cancelled');
    }

}
```

Comment: I thought of that, however I would prefer not to throw/catch exceptions as a regular part of running the software - it just feels wrong and I'd assume it would have significant performance implications.

Comment: @Daniel Agreed, exceptions should only be used for handling exceptional cases, not for 'regular' control flow. Unfortunately, I can't think of another way other than manually handling it as in your OP. :-/

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a sequence and you always test `cancelled` on your promises, you could create an interface that all you promises extend

```
interface Prom {
    cancelled?: boolean
}
```

Then run the sequence

```
const seq: Prom[] = [this.getPromise1(), this.getPromise2(),...]

for (let p of seq) {
    const res = await p
    if (res.cancelled) {
        return this.revert()
    }
}
```

Alternatively if you make your promises to `reject` instead of setting the result to `cancelled` (which is what I would do), you can benefit from the fail fast behaviour of [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

```
try {
    await Promise.all([this.getPromise1(), this.getPromise2(),...])
catch(e) {
    //a promise was rejected
}
```

Handling exceptions cannot really be avoided when using `await`.
So if you do not want to handle exceptions, use `then`

```
Promise.all([this.getPromise1(), this.getPromise2(),...]).then(
    () => { //success },
    (reason) => { // failure }
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately this doesn't allow for the very important functionality I need, namely the ability to use the result of one promise as input for the next promise. As for exception handling, I don't hind handling exceptions however I would like to avoid throwing them in non-exceptional circumstances.